# Resources files in Go

Tags: go

I've got some binary files that are required to run some `_test` cases.

Currently the relative paths to these files are hardcoded into the tests, which I don't like since the tests break if you change anything in the folder hierarchy and make the tests fragile.

Is there a preferred best practice for handling this, and resource files in general?

Comment: While I'm with @jnml on this, there seems to be [the way to simulate resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12483181/720999) in compiled Go files using the `go-binary` package. It's an external dependency though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The testing resource name may be hard coded but the path doesn't have to be.

```
(09:13) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$ ls -a
.  ..  a_test.go
(09:13) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$ cat a_test.go 
package foo

import (
        "testing"
        "io/ioutil"
)

func Test(t *testing.T) {
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("foo")
        if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
        }

        t.Logf("resource content is: %s", b)
}
(09:13) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$ go test -v
=== RUN Test
--- FAIL: Test (0.00 seconds)
a_test.go:11:         open foo: no such file or directory
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL        tmp/SO/13854048        0.005s
(09:14) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$
```

Correct, no such resource (yet). Let's create it.

```
(09:14) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$ echo blah > foo
(09:14) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$ go test -v
=== RUN Test
--- PASS: Test (0.00 seconds)
a_test.go:14:         resource content is: blah
PASS
ok          tmp/SO/13854048        0.007s
(09:14) jnml@fsc-r550:~/src/tmp/SO/13854048$ cd
(09:14) jnml@fsc-r550:~$ go test -v tmp/SO/13854048
=== RUN Test
--- PASS: Test (0.00 seconds)
a_test.go:14:         resource content is: blah
PASS
ok          tmp/SO/13854048        0.005s
(09:14) jnml@fsc-r550:~$
```

Note (in the last run above) that the cwd is correct even when `go test` is invoked from elsewhere.

Comment: But in this case the resource file has to be in the source folder, as far as I could tell.