# How to solve template: pattern matches no files

Tags: file, go, embedded-resource, go-templates

How to handle file path when i am accessing file from other go file than main.

in other.go file i am trying to run ParseFS but it's giving the template: pattern matches no files: `templates/test.tmpl` error. Here is my file tree.

```
├── go.mod
├── main
│   └── main.go
└── other
    ├── other.go
    └── templates
        └── test.tmpl
```

other/other.go

```
package other

import (
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

var templateFS embed.FS

func Check() error {
    _, err := template.New("email").ParseFS(templateFS, "templates/"+ "test.tmpl")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

main/main.go

```
func main() {
    err :=othher.Check()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely you have an incorrect `//go:embed` directive before `templateFS` which you carefully omitted from the answer. Please show that.

Comment: Your templateFS is empty because you have not provided any **directives**. Read about directives here: https://pkg.go.dev/embed@go1.17.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go is a statically linked language. Whatever source you write, in the end the `go` tool will compile it into an executable binary. The source files will not be required afterwards to run the binary.

The [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package gives you a mean to include static files in the executable binary which you can access at runtime (the original, included files don't need to be present when you run the app).

However, the `go` tool will not magically find out what files and folders you want to include in your binary. It will obviously not include everything you have in your source or module's folder.

The way to tell which files you want to be included is a special `//go:embed` comment preceding the variable you want the files to be stored in.

So in your case you have to put the following comment before your `templateFS` variable:

```
//go:embed templates/*
var templateFS embed.FS
```

Also note that embedding only works if you import the `embed` package. This "naturally" happens in your case because you used the `embed.FS` type (which requires importing the `embed` package), but if you would include a file in a variable of `string` or `[]byte` type, that wouldn't require importing `embed`, in which case you'd have to do a "blank" import like

```
import _ "embed"
```

More details are in the package doc of [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed).

See related question: [What's the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904441/whats-the-best-way-to-bundle-static-resources-in-a-go-program/28071360#28071360)