# Code has to load a font file, how to embed inside the built binary

Tags: go, fonts, truetype

I have this code inside a Go package of mine. It must load the `cmr10.ttf` font file. So, the font file must be next to every executable which is using this package.

```golang
import (
    "github.com/deadsy/sdfx/sdf"
)

func Text(txt string, height, thickness, roundness float32) (sdf.SDF3, error) {
    f, err := sdf.LoadFont("cmr10.ttf")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    t := sdf.NewText(txt)

    s2d, err := sdf.TextSDF2(f, t, float64(height))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Extrude the 2D SDF to a 3D SDF.
    return sdf.ExtrudeRounded3D(s2d, float64(thickness), float64(roundness))
}
```

## Question

Is there a way to avoid copying the `cmr10.ttf` font file next to any executable using this package?

For example, like embedding the font file into the built binary. If possible, how to exactly do it?

Any other idea to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Go 1.16 the go tool has support for embedding static files directly in the executable binary. You can embed the binary data of the font file using the `//go:embed` directive:

```
import (
    _ "embed"
)

//go:embed cmr10.ttf
var cmr10FontData []byte
```

The content of `cmr10.ttf` will be inserted into the `cmr10FontData` variable by the compiler. For other options see [What's the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904441/whats-the-best-way-to-bundle-static-resources-in-a-go-program/28071360#28071360)

Now since `github.com/deadsy/sdfx/sdf` only offers an [`sdf.LoadFont(fname)`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/deadsy/sdfx/sdf#LoadFont) helper function, you have to use [`github.com/golang/freetype/truetype`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/freetype/truetype) to parse the font data. Note that `sdf.LoadFont()` also uses this under the hood, calling [`truetype.Parse()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/freetype/truetype#Parse) with the binary data of the font file:

```
f, err := truetype.Parse(cmr10FontData)
// Check error
// use f if no error
```