# Parse content of files in subdirectories with golang templates

Tags: go, templates, krakend

We have structure of files like

```
dir1/file.json
fir2/file.json
dir3/file.json
test.tmpl
```

How to include content of all files like

```
{{range . }}
   {{ include . }}
 {{end}}
```

I tried to use examples from https://www.krakend.io/docs/configuration/templates/
But it doesn't work like i expected.

Comment: Use the `embed` package and feature to include the `.json` files in the executable, and pass them to the template execution as a parameter. See [What's the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904441/whats-the-best-way-to-bundle-static-resources-in-a-go-program/28071360#28071360) If you don't want to include those files in the executable, you must read them at runtime, and pass the read content as parameters as suggested before.