# Golang Echo Labstack serve static files with Go embed

Tags: go

I am building a web app frontend with Go, however after building and using go embed, it seems that all static files are not served and cannot be found. I am using Echo framework, serving the web app on AWS EC2 Linux with systemctl service.

main.go

```
type TemplateRenderer struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

func (t *TemplateRenderer) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {

    // Add global methods if data is a map
    if viewContext, isMap := data.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
        viewContext["reverse"] = c.Echo().Reverse
    }

    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

//go:embed app/views/*/*.tmpl static/*
var content embed.FS

func main() {
    echo.NotFoundHandler = func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(404, "404_not_found", controllers.PageData(c, nil))
    }
    e := echo.New()
    e.Pre(middleware.RemoveTrailingSlash())
    e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("175f678f62fdef4630b40d388d18bddd469925dd5e4c7428af63fcf0b9dc096c"))))

    renderer := &TemplateRenderer{
        // templates: template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{

        templates: template.Must(template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
            "URLEscape":               util.URLEscape,
        }).ParseFS(content, "app/views/*/*.tmpl")),
    }
    e.Renderer = renderer

    routes.Routes(e)

    e.Use(middleware.Static(""))
    e.Use(middleware.Static("static"))
    e.Static("/static", "static")

    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8187"))
}
```

If I use go build and run the app ./app it works fine, but if I use the service (systemctl start app), all the static files are not found. Seems like I'm missing a step but couldn't get it to work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata) (`go get -u github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata/...`), mentioned in "[What is the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904528/6309)".
It is a tool that converts any static file into Go code, which can be then included and compiled with your application. That way, you can distribute your application as a single binary without external dependencies on static files. The generated Go code includes a function for each embedded file which returns the file content as a byte slice when called.

Generate Go code for your static files and templates:

```bash
go-bindata -o bindata.go static/... app/views/...
```

And update your `main.go` to use the generated `bindata.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:   "bindata:/static",
        Browse: true,
    }))

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Blob(200, "text/html; charset=utf-8", Asset("static/index.html"))
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8187"))
}
```

The `middleware.StaticWithConfig` and `c.Blob` functions are used to serve the embedded static files from `bindata.go`.
That setup should work when the application is run directly or via systemd service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try to implement this go-bindata first