# Directory structure for Go web app

Tags: templates, web-applications, go, directory-structure

I've followed the [Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) tutorial on the Go website and I'm starting to write my own web app. I've also read the beginning of [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) and am trying to organise my code with the same workspace structure.

I'm writing a simple web app named mygosite that handles all requests by rendering a single template. After running `go install github.com/wesleym/mygosite`, my directory structure now looks like this:

```
go
+-src
| +-github.com
|   +-wesleym
|     +-mygosite
|       +-mygosite.go
|       +-templates
|         +- index.html
|       +-.git
+-bin
  +-mygosite
```

In my code, I'm referring to the template with path `templates/index.html`. When I run `bin/mygosite`, the app can't find my template because it's in the source tree. Since the templates are important to my app, I don't want to move them outside of my mygosite git repository.

Is my directory layout reasonable given what I'm trying to do? Should I change the path to my template in my code to be `src/github.com/wesleym/mygosite/templates/index.html`? What about static assets like CSS and JavaScript - where should those go when the time comes to introduce them?

*tl;dr: Where do I put templates and static files in a Go web application project?*

Comment: Update Jan. 2021: Go 1.16 will come with embedded files: see [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27010732/6309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where do I put templates and static files in a Go web application project?

is the "wrong" question. If you ask "How will my executable find its resources?" you are almost at the solution: Your executable should read its resources from a (or several) locations which are configurable (and it is always nice to provide sensible defaults). Command line flags, environment variables and config files in the current working directory are common for such tasks. (Of course, if you just have a handful of small resources: Pack them into your executable as VonC recommended; this scheme just breaks down once you start including large assets like images or video.)

Answer (score 4):

Update 2021, with [Go 1.16](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16#library-embed), you would use:

> The new [`embed` package](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/embed/) provides access to files embedded in the program during compilation using the new `//go:embed` directive.

See "[Embedding files in Go using the "embed" package](https://echorand.me/posts/go-embed/)", from [Amit Saha](https://twitter.com/echorand) (SRE at @Atlassian) who does embed a template in his project.

> ```golang
> //go:embed templates/main.go.tmpl
> var tmplMainGo []byte
> ```
>
> This makes the contents of the above template available as a slice of bytes in the `tmplMainGo` variable.
>
> We can then access the template as follows:
>
> ```golang
> tmpl, err := tmpl.Parse(string(tmplMainGo))
> ```

See a demo at [`amitsaha/go-embed`](https://github.com/amitsaha/go-embed).

See also "[Working with Embed in Go 1.16 Version](https://lakefs.io/working-with-embed-in-go/)" from [Barak Amar](https://twitter.com/nopcoder) and his own [demo project](https://github.com/treeverse/blogs/tree/master/mypostcard).

---

Original answer2014: You could consider using the project [`jteeuwen/go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) (archived in 2018)

> This package converts any file into managable Go source code. Useful for embedding binary data into a go program. The file data is optionally gzip compressed before being converted to a raw byte slice.

You can see it used in "[golang embed file for later parsing execution use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12483181/6309)"

That same page also mention [`GeertJohan/go.rice`](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice) as an alternative

Another recent good tool comes from [esc: Embedding Static Assets in Go](http://mattjibson.com/blog/2014/11/19/esc-embedding-static-assets/)

> a program that:
>
> - can take some directories and recursively embed all files in them in a way that was compatible with http.FileSystem
> - can optionally be disabled for use with the local file system for local development
> - will not change the output file on subsequent runs
> - has reasonable-sized diffs when files changed
> - is vendoring-friendly

Comment: Please be aware that the [jteeuwen/go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) repository has been archived by the owner. The last commit was made on Mar 4, 2018.

Comment: @MatthewRankin Thank you. I have updated the answer to use the Go 1.16 new embed feature instead of that old project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want template-nesting (somewhat like template-inheritance), try: [go(golang) template manager, especially for web development](https://github.com/darkdarkfruit/templatemanager)
.

A Suggest templates layout could be:

```
templates/
├── context
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── layout.tpl.html
│   └── partial
│       └── ads.tpl.html
└── main
    └── demo
        ├── demo1.tpl.html
        ├── demo2.tpl.html
        └── dir1
            └── dir2
                └── any.tpl.html
```

[demo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b53HP.png)

[demo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1vuV.png)

[any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnlHt.png)