# Go: embed static files in binary

Tags: go

This might be a very amateur question. I'm trying to embed static files into binary, ie. html. How do I  do that with https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata?

So I can access an asset with this https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata#accessing-an-asset, but what do I do with "data", and how to do I parse files, execute template, and serve them in the directory?

I couldn't find any examples online, and will appreciate some help!

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27010732/6309?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a directory structure like so:

```
example/
    main.go
    data/hi.html
```

example/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var tmpl *template.Template

func init() {
    data, err := Asset("data/hi.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tmpl = template.Must(template.New("tmpl").Parse(string(data)))
}

func main() {
    // print to stdout
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]string{"Name": "James"})

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        tmpl.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Name": "James"})
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

example/data/hi.html

```
<h1>Hi, {{.Name}}</h1>
```

run like so:

```
go-bindata data && go build && ./example
```

Console Output:

```
<h1>Hi, James</h1>
```

HTTP output:

## Hi, James

Comment: thanks for that! what's about serving JS files? I tried to pass them in a struct form into the html template in tmpl.Execute. The JS error I got was this  GET http://localhost:8000/*!%20jQuery%20v2.1.3%20%7c%20%28c%29%202005,%202014%2…%7c[%5c%5cw-]%7c[%5e%5c%5cx00-%5c%5cxa0]%29+%22,N=M.replace%28%22w%22,%22w

Comment: @user3918985 that looks like your JS file is getting escaped by the html template. If you just want to serve the contents of a file from your binary you do not need to use `html/template` just serve the contents you get from the `Asset` function. In a `HandleFunc` you could just use the `w http.ResponseWriter` to write out the Asset data like `w.Write(data)`

Comment: wow.. but I have to write each data individually? Or can I serve them in one directory? I'm trying now.

Comment: hmm I get the entire file contents printed on the page.. Im trying to write css file

Comment: I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903565/go-embed-js-files-with-bindata?noredirect=1#comment44209499_27903565

Answer (score 9):

5/6 years later, this should be easier with Go 1.16 (Q1 2021), which adds support for embedded files ([issue/proposal 41191](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41191) )

> It will be permitted to use `//go:embed` naming a single file to initialize a plain `string` or `[]byte` variable:

```
//go:embed gopher.png
var gopherPNG []byte
```

The import is required to flag the file as containing `//go:embed` lines and needing processing.
`Goimports` (and `gopls` etc) can be taught this rule and automatically add the import in any file with a `//go:embed` as needed.

That sparked a debate on [issue 42328](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42328) about how to avoid surprising inclusion of "hidden" files when using `//go:embed`

This as resolved in [CL 275092](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/275092/) and [commit 37588ff](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/37588ffcb221c12c12882b591a16243ae2799fd1)

> Decision to exclude files matching `.*` and `_*` from embedded directory results when embedding an entire directory tree.

See [`src/embed/internal/embedtest/embed_test.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/37588ffcb221c12c12882b591a16243ae2799fd1/src/embed/internal/embedtest/embed_test.go)

```golang
    //go:embed testdata/k*.txt
    var local embed.FS
    testFiles(t, local, "testdata/ken.txt", "If a program is too slow, it must have a loop.\n")

    //go:embed testdata/k*.txt
    var s string
    testString(t, s, "local variable s", "If a program is too slow, it must have a loop.\n")

    //go:embed testdata/h*.txt
    var b []byte
    testString(t, string(b), "local variable b", "hello, world\n")
```

Note: with [CL 281492](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/281492/), `cmd/go` passes `embedcfg` to `gccgo` if supported.

---

See also (Jan. 2021) [issue 43854](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43854) "opt-in for `//go:embed` to *not* ignore files and empty dirs".