# Go: embed JS files with bindata

Tags: go

This question is a follow up to an earlier question of mine. I've closed the question so I hope its okay that I ask a fresh but related question here. [Go: embed static files in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889779/go-embed-static-files-in-binary)

How do I serve JS files with go-bindata? Do I pass it into html like this

hi.html

```
<script>{{.Bindata}}></script>
```

Doesn't seem to work even though I have no compile or JS errors.

Comment: Remember to convert the JavaScript into a template.HTML() before passing it to the template so it does not get escaped.

Comment: yup, even css is escaped.. I'm trying to fix this <style>ZgotmplZ</style>

Comment: converting the fields to template.HTML doesn't seem to help though

Comment: Strange. Try to convert it into template.JS instead. Maybe that works.

Comment: nope its CSS. no problems with JS escaping

Comment: If you are looking to use this like a file server check out github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs

Comment: @jmaloney what are the other ways if I just use bindata alone?

Comment: @user3918985 you would have to setup a route for each file you wanted to serve. If you are just trying to serve files from your binary I would strongly recommend using `go-bindata-assetfs` since that is what it was designed to do.

Comment: got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906812/go-unescape-css-input-in-html/27907002#27907002

Answer (score 2):

Using https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs

Assuming you have the following structure:

```
myprojectdirectory
├───api
├───cmd
├───datastores
└───ui
    ├───css
    └───js
```

Where `ui` is the directory structure you'd like to wrap up and pack into your app...

## Generate a source file

The [go-bindata-assetfs](https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs) tool is pretty simple.  It will look at the directories you pass to it and generate a source file with variables that can contain the binary data in those files.  So make sure your static files are there, and then run the following command from `myprojectdirectory`:

`go-bindata-assetfs ./ui/...`

Now, by default, this will create a source file in the package `main`.  Sometimes, this is ok.  In my case, it isn't.  You can generate a file with a different package name if you'd like:

`go-bindata-assetfs.exe -pkg cmd ./ui/...`

## Put the source file in the correct location

In this case, the generated file `bindata_assetfs.go` is created in the **myprojectdirectory** directory (which is incorrect).  In my case, I just manually move the file to the **cmd** directory.

## Update your application code

In my app, I already had some code that served files from a directory:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Create a router and setup routes
var Router = mux.NewRouter()    
Router.PathPrefix("/ui").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/ui", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ui"))))

// Start listening
http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:3000", Router)
```

Make sure something like this works properly, first.  Then it's trivial to change the FileServer line to:

```
Router.PathPrefix("/ui").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/ui", http.FileServer(assetFS())))
```

## Compile the app

Now you have a generated source file with your static assets in them.  You can now safely remove the 'ui' subdirectory structure.  Compile with

`go install ./...`

And you should have a binary that serves your static assets properly.

Comment: how the assetFs function appears in our code i cant understand this it is undefined theres no such exported methd from bindata_assetfs.go

Comment: Look at this source line in the package used to generate the assets: https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs/blob/master/go-bindata-assetfs/main.go#L76

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs

From the readme:

```
go-bindata-assetfs data/...
```

In your code setup a route with a file server

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(assetFS()))
```

Comment: seems to have lots of bugs. I can't even build it properly

Comment: @user3918985 what platform? Works for me on mac yosemite and debian. did `go get github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs/...` work?

Comment: yea I had these problems

./bindata_assetfs.go:9: imported and not used: "strings"
./bindata_assetfs.go:12: imported and not used: "io/ioutil"
./bindata_assetfs.go:13: imported and not used: "path"
./bindata_assetfs.go:14: imported and not used: "path/filepath"
./bindata_assetfs.go:107: undefined: _bintree
./bindata_assetfs.go:108: undefined: Asset
./bindata_assetfs.go:108: undefined: AssetDir

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer here: [Unescape css input in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906812/go-unescape-css-input-in-html/27907002#27907002)

```
var safeCss = template.CSS(`body {background-image: url("paper.gif");}`)
```