# Unescape css input in HTML

Tags: go, go-templates

How do I unescape html?

I'm passing a css file into html like this

```
<style>{{.file}}</style>
```

I get this

```
<style>ZgotmplZ</style>
```

I've tried wrapping the field with template.HTML(data), didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go HTML template package properly excapes CSS. Quoting from the [documentation of the `template` package](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/):

> The escaping is contextual, so actions can appear within JavaScript, CSS, and URI contexts.

`"ZgotmplZ"` is a special value, it is used as a replacement if the value you're trying to include is invalid or unsafe in the context.

So the problem is the CSS value you're trying to include, it is not safe. Try something simple first and see if it works, like:

```
body {background-color: #000}
```

Found the discussion of `"ZgotmplZ"` in the documentation (at type [`ErrorCode`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ErrorCode)), quoting it:

### `"ZgotmplZ"` explanation:

**Example Template:**

```
<img src="{{.X}}">
where {{.X}} evaluates to `javascript:...`
```

**Discussion:**

```
"ZgotmplZ" is a special value that indicates that unsafe content reached a
CSS or URL context at runtime. The output of the example will be
  <img src="#ZgotmplZ">
If the data comes from a trusted source, use content types to exempt it
from filtering: URL(`javascript:...`).
```

### Solution

Since the code you try to insert is in the context of CSS code and not HTML, you can't/shouldn't use `template.HTML(data)`.

There is a predefined type [`CSS`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#CSS) for safe inclusion of CSS code coming from trusted source, e.g. CSS code you specify and is not coming from an HTML form filled by the user. Example:

```
var safeCss = template.CSS(`body {background-image: url("paper.gif");}`)
```

And pass the `safeCss` value to your template parameter.

Comment: Thank you for showing us `template.CSS`. It's hard to get straightforward solutions for this.