# How to not escape in HTML templates

Tags: go, template-engine, go-html-template

Trying to render HTML templates for sending via email with embedded attachments with `cid:`. Problem is, that Go does escaping and I cannot do anything.

```
tplVars := map[string]interface{}{
    "Dog": "cid:dog.png",
    "Cat": "cid:cat.png",
}
```

My testing template looks more less like this:

```
Dog: <img src="{{.Dog}}">
Cat: {{.Cat}}
```

Output is:

```
Dog: <img src="#ZgotmplZ">
Cat: cid:cat.png
```

If text is outside attribute context, it is evaluated correctly, but when it is an `src` attribute it always become that error string. I tried also change value from `string` to `template.HTMLAttr` but nothing happen. Cid value is always evaluated to that error output `#ZgotmplZ`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of ZgotmplZ from html/template in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382624/how-to-get-rid-of-zgotmplz-from-html-template-in-golang) and [Go: unescape css input in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906812/go-unescape-css-input-in-html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that the `src` attribute isn't treated strictly as an attribute, but as a URL.  If you change it from a `string` to a `template.URL` it works just fine.

```
tplVars := map[string]interface{}{
    "Dog": template.URL("cid:dog.png"),
    "Cat": "cid:cat.png",
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZN27nGnUE9

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I'm totally blind. I tried all possible types as HTML, HTMLAttr, even CSS etc. But I didn't see URL type and the end of index. Thank you

Comment: Arrrgh this _ought_ to be on the documentation **somewhere**. The hours I've lost trying to figure it out on my own!! Thanks for posting an answer, though. It was _really_ helpful (even 6 years later!)