# How can I build a Go app with a ReactJS GUI in a single binary?

Tags: reactjs, go

I would like to develop a Go application with a ReactJS "GUI".
My point is to launch a single binary "app" that launch a server at "localhost:someport" serving a ReactJS app.
I would like my actions in the ReactApp to be taken into account in the Go-side app.

I can do a Websocket-based ReactJS-Go application but I'd like everything to be bundled into a single binary.
I've followed this : https://medium.com/@esslamben/serving-static-sites-with-go-55bfc1ae4495.
This tutorial helped me to serve static files (a React App) with a single file.
But, I don't know how to continue to satisfy my wishes.

The thing I would like to achieve is the behavior like the old "RethinkDB".
When you run "rethinkdb.exe" in command line, it notifies a administration panel is running on 8080 port.
Navigating through localhost:8080 enables to administrate the database with a web-based GUI.

Does someone have advice to help me to obtain such a behavior?

Comment: you can create a docker image for this and can launch 2 apps within the same docker image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12482311/13860

Comment: 1. I should try Docker

2. I would like something different from serving templates. I would like a way to act on the Go model through the ReactJS view the way websocket enable to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make binary for your React code , it should be copied

1. Your react built code (I assume static ) and put it in a specific path
2. Use Go http FileServer handler to serve the app as static one. 
   This might work or may not , I am not sure what are the bindings which is necessary should alos be copied. (your node modules and additional libraries you use it in your package.json)

Answer (score 0):

Put your *.js binary data inside an HTTP handler to serve the client.
Store your js file as an []byte inside your application.